# How to use gantry custom color

Tags: php, joomla, components, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I'm creating a component and actually I'm using Rocket Them Gantry 5 Template
actually i wanna add some block like

> Section Style

that include some block for change color of sections,
and admin can choose color and in my back end the color of a part of my component change

really nothing found after a day search

I'm really appreciated if someone can help me